# Does Visual Studio Publish to App Service feature deploys items in appsettings.json to the configuration blade in the Azure portal

Tags: visual-studio, azure-web-app-service

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to build an ASP .NET Core (v6) application.

I need to deploy and run my application on an `Azure App Services instance`.

I have many settings in my application's `appsettings.json` file. The file is included in the deployment package as shown here:

[image]

I use Visual Studio 2022 Publish feature to deploy my asp.net core application to an Azure App Services instance:

[image]

After a successful Visual Studio Publish, none of `appsettings.json` file settings show in the configuration blade:

[image]

**Questions:**

1- Is there any way Visual Studio publish feature deploy `appsettings.json` settings to the App Services' configuration blade?

2- Even after a successful deployment, my application does not read the settings in the `appsettings.json`. It seems that all ignored. I checked and on my local visual studio developer environment, my app reads  `appsettings.json`, but not when it is deployed to App Services. Why the deployed app ignores the `appsettings.json` settings?

**Update 1: `program.cs` and `appsettings.json`**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

    builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
    builder.Logging.AddConsole();
    builder.Logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics();

    // Add services to the container.
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

    builder.Services.AddControllers();
    // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
    builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
    builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

    builder.Services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
    builder.Services.AddScoped<Framework>();
        

    var app = builder.Build();

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUI();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();


    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
}
```

`appsettings.json` could be anything. Just need to read its content with a `ConfigurationManager` instance like how I read them when the site is running locally in Visual Studio.

Comment: Could you please share your `appsettings.json` and `Program.cs` file.

Comment: @Harshitha, just did. please see my Update #1.

Comment: Also please share your `.csroj `file as well.

Comment: Working on it will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there any way Visual Studio publish feature deploy appsettings.json` settings to the App Services' configuration blade?

The deployed `appsettings.json`  file will be available in KUDU Debug Console.

In your `Azure App Service` => `Advanced Tools` => `Go` => `Debug Console` => `cmd` => `site` => `wwwroot`.

[image]

- Or even you can open the `KUDU` with the below URL

```
https://YourAppServiceName.scm.azurewebsites.net/
```

- Configuration section will not display the setting which are in `appsettings.json` file. It is used to `override` the available settings from `appsettings.json`file.
- The values which you want to `override` and the new values which you want to add after deployment must be set in the `Application Settings` in portal.
- The key name must be same in both `appsettings.json` and `Configuration` => `Application` Settings.

[image]

***My  sample appsettings.json :***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyVal": "Local Connection"
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "MySettings": "Local Settings"
  }
}
```

***Code to retrieve values from appsettings.json***

```cs
var MyAppSettings = builder.Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
var LocalAppset = MyAppSettings.GetValue<string>("MySettings");
```

***OR***

```cs
var MyAppSettings1 = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AppSettings:MySettings");
```

***Index.cshtml***

```cs
@page
@model IndexModel
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

<h2>Configuration value for 'AppSettings': @Configuration["AppSettings:MySettings"]</h2>
```

- I have deployed the app and able to read the values from the deployed code.

***Initial Values***
[image]

***Overridden Values***
[image]

Comment: Thank you for help, in your example, for the app setting "AppSettings:MySettings" why the overridden key is AppSettings:MySettings1 in the poral screenshot you included?

Comment: Please change it to `AppSettings:MySettings`,was working with two more example keys.